# installing bookworm (debian 120 using qemu on windows

Tags: debian, windows-11, virtualization, qemu

Windows 11
Latest QEMU
Debian 12.4.0 netinstall

1. Installed QEMU as shown on various YouTube videos.
2. Created my image file with qemu-img.exe as follows;

   ```
   qemu-img create -f qcow2 debian.img 128G
   Formatting 'debian.img', fmt=qcow2 cluster_size=65536 extended_l2=off compression_type=zlib size=137438953472 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
   ```

   and `dir debian.img` shows `12/18/2023  05:15 PM           198,656 debian.img`
3. qemu-img info shows:

   ```
   image: debian.img
   file format: qcow2
   virtual size: 128 GiB (137438953472 bytes)
   disk size: 194 KiB
   cluster_size: 65536
   Format specific information:
       compat: 1.1
       compression type: zlib
       lazy refcounts: false
       refcount bits: 16
       corrupt: false
       extended l2: false
    Child node '/file':
        filename: debian.img
        protocol type: file
        file length: 194 KiB (198656 bytes)
        disk size: 194 KiB
   ```
4. When I try to install Debian into this image, I get the nice GUI install, but then it throws an error. Command used is

   ```
   qemu-system-x86_64 -drive          file=debian.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom .\debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso -m 4G -L Bios -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -boot menu=on -rtc          base=localtime,clock=host -parallel none -serial none -name debian -machine acpi=off,hpet=off -no-reboot
   ```

   The error thrown indicates that the actual file size is being checked (194k) instead of the virtual disk space (128G)
5. I could not get `--preallocation-full` to work either on resize or as an argument to -o on the create (without the (`--`).

Help?

Comment: Check that your BIOS is set for Hardware Virtualization (VT-D)